# Best way to do multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

What might be the best way to use multiprocessing in which the results of each process is required in the main process?

Suppose, I have a list of students id. For each student, I need to apply the operation like reading the student's data and calculating the overall results of the student. Each process then stores the end results to the multiprocessing manager dictionary. The dictionary will be then processed in the main process to and saved to the database.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def main():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    student_dict = manager.dict()
    processes = []
    for student_id in student_ids:
       process = multiprocessing.process(target=process_student,
                                      args=student_dict)
       processes.append(process)
       process.start()

    for key, value in student_dict.items():
         #save to db

for process in processes:
    process.join()

def process_student():
    read_student()
    calculate_student_results()

def read_student():
    #operation

def calculate_student_results():
    #operation
    student_dict[key] = value
```

I am worried if this is the right way to do because in many tutorials they say not to use the shared state and use the queue. But when I used the queue the process hanged. might be because of the huge number of results in the queue.

Can I do this way or should I use any another way for multiprocessing? Also is there any chance of deadlock in the process.

Comment: Both methods are valid when you want to achieve concurrency. You need to understand your problem to tell which one is better. You can run distinct threads and send message from one to another or have they to share state.

Sending messages are more general and easier to maintain, because the actors respond to messages as they arrive and nothing is shared. In another words you achieve a better level of encapsulation. The problem with this approach is that sending and receiving a message inflict on a overhead, a penality.

Comment: As more communication is needed more penality you will suffer. The other option is shared state. In this approach you send no messages but share a state. The problem where is that you need to synchronize the access to the shared state so it keeps valid. This has worse encapsulation and because of this more care is needed and more complex is to handle the problem rightfully. You may suffer from deadlocks and rise of code complexity and verbosity

Comment: To choose you have to think wisely. What you need? I'm a very biased to JIT approach but this is a preference of mine. I would start with no parallelism, add messaging if needed, try shared state in sequence, and lock free algorithm next. To choose between shared state and messaging you need to answer these questions: How many work you can do with a single message? Is the messaging logic flooded? Can I make it better by mutexing it?